# openvpn (PIA) can't access WAN

Tags: openvpn, vpn

I am trying to get my machine to use PIA/openvpn.

I have a sonicwall device with the following setup.

---

WAN Network 10.0.0.0

ISP Router 10.0.0.20

LAN Network 10.0.10.0

Sonicwall 10.0.10.10

My Computer 10.0.10.60

---

Not connected ifconfig:

```
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:ee:23:e1:ec:ca  
          inet addr:10.0.10.60  Bcast:10.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: eeee::eee:23ff:fee1:ecca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:114346 (114.3 KB)  TX bytes:100276 (100.2 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)
```

Not connected route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.10.10      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.0.10.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

Connected ifconfig

```
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:ee:23:e1:ec:ca  
          inet addr:10.0.10.60  Bcast:10.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: eeee::eee:23ff:fee1:ecca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:740 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:130187 (130.1 KB)  TX bytes:111051 (111.0 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12320 (12.3 KB)  TX bytes:12320 (12.3 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.12.10.6  P-t-P:10.12.10.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Connected route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.12.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         10.0.10.10      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.0.10.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
10.12.10.1      10.12.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.12.10.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.12.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
176.22.21.200   10.0.10.10      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp5s0
```

When connected, I cannot access the internet.

I can ping devices on my LAN (say, 10.0.10.10 / sonicwall)... but not WAN (say 10.0.0.20 / router) or google.com

I understand I need to add a route, but I don't know what.

Any input appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: `ip -4 route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.10.10 dev enp5s0`.  Your question is incomplete (missing netmask on some of the addresses), but assuming a `/24` on what you call the WAN segment, something like this should work.

Comment: Chuck up an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Also, how can I add this to the openvpn config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to as the WAN Network is still local (so cannot be accessed through the VPN tunnel), but is a distinct subnet from your LAN segment.  You need to add a route *to* the network `10.0.0.0/24` using the local gateway (visible in your routes prior to bringing up the tunnel) `10.0.10.10`.  Putting it together

```
ip -4 route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.10.10 dev enp5s0
```

---

In this setup, you could make this route permanent, instead of toggling it when the OpenVPN tunnel changed state.  You need the route when the VPN is up; when the VPN is down, it is mildly redundant, but does no harm.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to add this to the openvpn config pls?